# Data missing in Carbon on Laravel Many to Many relation

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I recently change my database from from MySql to MSSql and I'm having problems with date formats. I changed all models to use `$dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s'` and work's fine, but today I'm having problem with a model that have a relation many-to-many with other model.

My database are saving the dates in format Y-m-d H:i:s.000, in this way 2018-08-20 16:01:12.000. I think that eloquent aren't respecting the date format.

I'm using Laravel 5.4 and php 5.6;

Today, I'm getting this error

```
InvalidArgumentException in Carbon.php line 909:
Data missing

in Carbon.php line 909

at Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s.000', '2018-07-19 10:40:21') in Model.php line 3003
```

The code that are generate the error,

```
public function getDetailQuiz()
{
    $quiz_id = Input::get('quiz_id');

    *$quiz = QuizTopic::with('questions.answers')->where('id', $quiz_id)->first();*

    foreach ($quiz->questions as $question) {
        $answers = [];
        $answer_order = 0;

        foreach ($question->answers as $i => $answer) {
            $answers[] = ['answer' => $answer->description, 'id' => $answer->id, 'action' => 'update'];

            if ($question->answer_id == $answer->id) $answer_order = $i;
        }

        $response['questions'][] = [
            'id'             => $question->id,
            'question'       => $question->description,
            'correct_answer' => $question->answer_id,
            'points'         => $question->points,
            'answers'        => $answers,
            'action'         => 'update',
            'answer_order'   => $answer_order,
        ];
    }

    $quiz->start_date = Carbon::parse($quiz->start_date)->format('d/m/Y H:i');
    $quiz->end_date = Carbon::parse($quiz->end_date)->format('d/m/Y H:i');

    $response['quiz'] = $quiz->makeVisible(['award_value', 'type_id', 'start_date', 'end_date'])->toArray();


    return response()->json(['result' => $response]);
}
```

My QuizTopic Model

```
class QuizTopic extends Model
    {
        protected $table   = 'quiz_topics';
        protected $guarded = ['id'];
        protected $hidden  = [
            'created_at',
            'updated_at',
            'deleted_at',
            'created_user_id',
            'updated_user_id',
            'winner_clerk_id',
            'award_value',
            'status_id',
            'type_id',
            'start_date',
            'end_date',
            'raffle_date',
            'fcm_notification_reference',
        ];
        protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i';

        use SoftDeletes;

        public function questions()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\QuizQuestion', 'rel_topics_questions', 'topic_id', 'question_id')->withTimestamps();
        }


    }
```

My QuizQuestion Model

```
class QuizQuestion extends Model
    {
        protected $table   = 'quiz_questions';
        protected $guarded = ['id'];
        protected $hidden  = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at','points','pivot','created_user_id','updated_user_id'];
        protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';

        use SoftDeletes;

        public function topics()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\QuizTopic');
        }

        public function answers()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\QuizAnswer', 'rel_questions_answers', 'question_id', 'answer_id')->withTimestamps();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You say your are storing the date in the `Y-m-d H:i:s.000` format but Carbon is trying to convert a date without  milliseconds `2018-07-19 10:40:21`. Are you sure the stored dates are properly formated?

Comment: Strange, because all others models doesn't have this same problem, just that. I'll try to change the format and save and get the result to test.

Answer (score 2):

From the manual:

> By default, timestamps are formatted as 'Y-m-d H:i:s'. If you need to
>   customize the timestamp format, set the $dateFormat property on your
>   model. This property **determines how date attributes are stored in the
>   database**, as well as their format when the model is serialized to an
>   array or JSON

(emphasis mine)

Since you're saving your dates as `Y-m-d H:i:s.000`, you need to set the `$dateFormat` property in both of your models as such:

```
protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s.000';
```

Change that and try again.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I changed, but the problem persists. When I change the $dateFormat from Y-m-d H:i:s to Y-m-d H:i:s.000,  my QuizTopic Model stops working and show the same error that QuizQuestion model ( Data Missing ).

Comment: Can you share the code where the error is happening? Not just the one line, but the surrounding code as well.

Comment: Yes, I updated my post, like I said the problem is when I use the ::with('questions'). Thanks!

Comment: Did you change the $dateFormat property in your QuizAnswer model as well?

Comment: Yes, but don't worked. The solution was change the format of the dates in database to smalldatetime and set $dateFormat on the Models to Y-m-d H:i:s.